# I can move an ImageView only if its size is match_parent

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I made a program that moves an ImageView around the screen. This is the code:

layout.xml

```
<it.lorfioroni.scanner.customImageView
    android:id="@+id/customImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

customImageView.java

```
public class customImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
public customImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public customImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public customImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

private int xDelta, yDelta;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)
                    this.getLayoutParams();

            xDelta = x - lParams.leftMargin;
            yDelta = y - lParams.topMargin;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           Log.i("ciao", "thanks for new location");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) this
                    .getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = x - xDelta;
            layoutParams.topMargin = y - yDelta;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
            this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
    }
    if(this.getParent() instanceof View)
        ((View)this.getParent()).invalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

And it works, I can move the image freely in the screen. The problem is that while the image is small on the left corner (that's ok), the imageView is fullscreen... I tried to set

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

but when I do that, the imageView won't move anymore. Do you have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking.

Comment: My code permits to touch and drag an imageView with the finger, to move it in the screen. While the imageView  is matching the parent, the image itself is small and in the left corner. Since the imageview is big, I can touch and move it also if the finger is not on top of the image. I don't want it to act like that, so I tried to resize the imageview to wrap the content. The problem is that if the imageview is of the same size of the image, I don't know why but it doesn't move anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was that in ConstraintLayout I was setting the margins without setting the constraints. 
I've added

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
```

and now it works